# How to specify percent in Access Form without multiplying by 100

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access form that I want to show a percentage in. The data is coming from a SQL backend and is an `Int`. Whenever I set the Format for that field in Access to be `Percent` it multiplies the value by 100. I just want to add the `%` sign behind the value. I've tried a custom format like `0\%`, but that doesn't work. Access removes the `\` and considers it to still be set to `Percent`.

How can I format the number to have a `%` added to the end of it without multiplying it by 100?

**Update**

If I try to change the Data's Control Source to be `=[Source]/100` i get an error like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to do this on the Control's Format property. If so, try this: @%

Comment: I tried that, when I use 15 as the percent it gives me 1500@%

Comment: You said the table is in the sql sever, is your form bound directly to a linked table, or do you have a local query that is reading the linked table?

Comment: It's a linked table. There is a query that pulls the data for the form. I didn't create the Access file, I'm just the one stuck trying to fix it.

Comment: Never mind this does work. I was trying it like `0@%` and that didn't work, but doing it like this does: `@%`. Not sure why you can't have the preceding 0, but it doesn't work if you do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bind your textbox to:

```
=[YourIntegerField]/100
```

and set the *Format* property to: Percent

Comment: I've tried that I get an error it says that makes it a circular reference. I'll add an update to my question.

Comment: Rename the textbox.